# Java - Calling methods from other classes with calculated fields

Tags: java, class, methods

So I've been looking at this piece of code all afternoon and I can't see the error(s). Here is what I'm supposed to do:

Create a `Delivery` class for a delivery service. The class contains fields to hold the following:

- A delivery number that contains eight digits. The first four digits represent the year, and the last four digits represent the delivery number.
- A code representing the delivery area. A local delivery is code 1, and a long distance delivery is code 2.
- A weight, in pounds, of the item to be delivered.
- The fee for the delivery, as follows:

Create a constructor for the `Delivery` class that accepts arguments for the year,
delivery number within the year, delivery distance code, and weight of the package. The
constructor determines the eight-digit delivery number and delivery fee. Also include a
method that displays every `Delivery` object field. Save the file as Delivery.java.

Next, create an application that prompts the user for data for a delivery. Keep
prompting the user for each of the following values until they are valid:

- A four-digit year between 2001 and 2025 inclusive
- A delivery number for the year between 1 and 9999 inclusive
- A package weight between 0.10 pound and 100 pounds inclusive
- A delivery distance code that is either 1 or 2

When all the data entries are valid, construct a `Delivery` object, and then display its
values. Save the file as `CreateDelivery.java`.

So here is my delivery Class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;


class Delivery 
{
    //variables
    private int year;
    private int deliveryNumber; //deliveryNo
    private double weight;
    private int distanceCode; //code

        //constructor
        //Delivery()
        //{
        //  year = year;
        //  deliveryNumber = deliveryNumber;
        //  weight = weight;
        //  distanceCode = distanceCode;
        //}

    //get year
    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }
    //set year
    public int setYear (int newYear)
    {
        year = newYear;
        return year;
    }

    //get deliveryNumber
    public int getDeliveryNumber()
    {
        return deliveryNumber;
    }
    //set deliveryNumber
    public int setDeliveryNumber (int newDeliveryNumber)
    {
        deliveryNumber = newDeliveryNumber;
        return deliveryNumber;
    }

    //get weight
    public double getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }
    //set Weight
    public double setWeight (double newWeight)
    {
        weight = newWeight;
        return weight;
    }   


    //get distanceCode
    public int getDistanceCode()
    {
        return distanceCode;
    }
    //set distanceCode
    public int setDistanceCode (int newDistanceCode)
    {
        distanceCode = newDistanceCode;
        return distanceCode;
    }   

    //calculate fee
    public double displayFees(int distance, double w) //distance = c
    {
        double fees = 0;

    if(distance == 1)
    {
            if(w < 5)
        {
            fees = 12;
        }
        else if((w < 20)&&(w > 5))
        {
            fees = 16.50;
        }
        else if(w > 20)
        {
            fees = 22;
        }
    }
    else if(distance == 2)
    {
        if(w < 5)
        {
            fees = 35;
        }
        else if(w >= 5)
        {
            fees = 47.95;
        }
    }
        return fees;
    }

    //display method
    public void display(int year, int deliveryNumber, double weight, int distanceCode)
        {
        System.out.println("Year: " + year + '\n' 
            + "Delivery Number: " + deliveryNumber + '\n' 
            + "Weight of the package: " + weight + '\n'
            + "Delivery code: " + distanceCode);
        }
}
```

And here is my CreateDelivery Class

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateDelivery
    {
        public static void main(String []args)

        {

            Delivery delivery1 = new Delivery();

            //scanner year
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter the current year, format (yyyy) >>> ");
            delivery1.setYear(input.nextInt());

            //loop year
                    while((delivery1.getYear() <= 2000)||(delivery1.getYear() >= 2026))
                    {
                        System.out.println('\n'+ "Error, year should be in the range of (2010 - 2025). Please enter a valid option >> ");
                        delivery1.setYear(input.nextInt());
                    }

            //scanner for delivery number
            System.out.print('\n'+ "Please enter a delivery number: ");
            delivery1.setDeliveryNumber(input.nextInt());

            //loop for delivery number
                    while((delivery1.getDeliveryNumber() <= 0001)||(delivery1.getDeliveryNumber() >= 10000))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error, the delivery number is a 4 digit number between 0001 and 9999, please enter a valid option >> ");
                        delivery1.setDeliveryNumber(input.nextInt());
                    }

            //scanner for weight
            System.out.print("Please enter the weight of the package (in pounds): ");
            delivery1.setWeight(input.nextDouble());

                    //loop for weight
                    while((delivery1.getWeight() <= .09)||(delivery1.getWeight() >= 101))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error, the minimum allowed weight is 0.10 pounds and the maximum is 100 pounds. Please enter a valid weight >> ");
                        delivery1.setWeight(input.nextDouble());
                    }

            //scanner for delivery code
            System.out.print("Please enter 1 for local or 2 for long distance deliveries >> ");
            delivery1.setDistanceCode(input.nextInt());

                    //loop for delivery code
                    while((delivery1.getDistanceCode() == 1) && (delivery1.getDistanceCode() == 2))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error, please enter a valid distance code (1 for local deliveries and 2 for long distance deliveries) >> ");
                        delivery1.setDistanceCode(input.nextInt());
                    }

            //turn int to string
            String n = Integer.toString(delivery1.getDeliveryNumber());
            String y = Integer.toString(delivery1.getYear());

            String trackingNumber = n + y;
            System.out.println(delivery1.getDistanceCode() + " " 
            + trackingNumber + " " + delivery1.getWeight() + " " + fees);

    }

}
```

So I made the changes you guys suggested, but now I can't pull fees from the Delivery class. Any thoughts?

Comment: What error you are facing?

Comment: Are `Delivery` and `CreateDelivery` in the same package?

Comment: //scanner for distance code
   System.out.print("Please enter 1 for local deliveries and 2 for long distance deliveries >> ");
   delivery1.setDistanceCode(input.nextInt());
   
     //loop for delivery code
     while(((delivery1.getDistanceCode()<=1)||(delivery1.getDistanceCode()>=2)))
     {
      System.out.println("Error, please enter a valid distance code (1 for local deliveries and 2 for long distance deliveries) >> ");
      delivery1.setDistanceCode(input.nextInt());
     }

Comment: Staring at code for hours is not a very effective debugging technique. For compilation erros, carefully reading the error message, and looking at the particular line of code referenced by the error, is far more productive. For unexpected runtime behaviour, Java has a great debugging tools - use them!

Comment: Also vague statements like *"... but now I can't pull fees from the Delivery class"* are not going to help anyone help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Delivery()
    {
        year = year;
        deliveryNumber = deliveryNumber;
        weight = weight;
        distanceCode = distanceCode;
    }
```

Replace it with something along the lines of:

```
Delivery(int year, int deliveryNumber, int weight, int distanceCode)
    {
        this.year = year;
        this.deliveryNumber = deliveryNumber;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.distanceCode = distanceCode;
    }
```

From there, I would avoid using the `set` methods. Instead, store all the values into respective fields as you load them from the `System.in`. Once you have all the fields, create the `Delivery` object.

Comment: I'm asked to set a constructor in the delivery class though.

Comment: ? Avoid set methods ? So your suggesting we should drop a basic OO principle?  While I can reason why you might suggest it in such a small example, the purpose of the question is to teach students appropriate paradigms.  And without know where this question might lead I (personally) find that suggestion worrisome

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'd be all for it, but the specifications require those to be set in the constructor. He could very well call the set methods inside the constructor. From what I saw as an intern at a company a while ago, is that deliveries, orders, things like that are often immutable.

Comment: Ah...in the constructor.  Yes, I can see that, I thought you meant altogether, my bad :P - As to immutable, that would come down to the rules of the requirements...

Comment: Now, I can't seem to be able to pull the fees field from Delivery into CreateDelivery, any ideas??

Comment: @ClaudiaBenitezdeArmstrong if this is a programming assignment, which it appears to be... at this point, it might be worth struggling a bit with - alone.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is that it looks fine according to all I know. Maybe I need a pair of rested eyes. I'll call it quits and try later. Thanks for everything guys!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `()` at the end of the methods such as `getDeliveryNumber`,`getYear` etc. in the while loop.
and you are also using undeclared variables at the end such as `getDeliveryNumber`,`getYear` etc.

Comment: I noticed that and I fix it, but now I can't get of the Distance loop, it prompts error even when I input a accepted variable

Comment: please remove `=` sign from your both condition in the while loop

Comment: @ClaudiaBenitezdeArmstrong your condition should be `while(delivery1.getDistanceCode() < 1 || delivery1.getDistanceCode() > 2) `

Answer (score 0):

or we can do that simply like Delivery class

```
public class Delivery {
private int year,deliveryNumber,distanceCode;
private double weight;
private double fees=0;

//delivery class constructor
public Delivery(int year,int deliveryNumber,int distanceCode,double weight)
{
    this.year=year;
    this.deliveryNumber=deliveryNumber;
    this.distanceCode=distanceCode;
    this.weight=weight;
}    
//calculate  delivery fee
public void displayFees(int distanceCode, double weight)
{
    if(distanceCode == 1)
        {
        if(weight<5)
        {
            fees = 12;
        }
        else if((weight < 20)&&(weight >=5))
        {
            fees = 16.50;
        }
        else if(weight > 20)
        {
            fees = 22;
        }
    }
    else if(distanceCode == 2)
    {
        if(weight <5)
        {
            fees = 35;
        }
        else if(weight >= 5)
        {
            fees = 47.95;
        }
    }
}
public double getFee()
{
    return fees;
}
```

}

and CreateDelivery class:

```
public class CreateDelivery {

public static void main(String[] args) {
            

    int year=(int)ReadValues.readValue("Year", 1999,2026);
    int deliveryNumber=(int)ReadValues.readValue("Delivery Number (1 to 10000)", 0,10000);
    int distanceCode=(int)ReadValues.readValue("DistanceCode (1 or 2)",0, 3);
    double weight=ReadValues.readValue("weight",0, 20);

    Delivery delivery=new Delivery(year, deliveryNumber, distanceCode, weight);
    delivery.displayFees(distanceCode, weight);
    double fee=delivery.getFee();

    System.out.println("\n\n*****Delivery Fees Details*****\n\nTrackingNumber:"+year+deliveryNumber+"\nDistanceCode:"+distanceCode+"\nFee :"+fee);
}
```

}

and for reading values from user another class called ReadValue

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class ReadValues {

```
public static double readValue(String prompt, int min, int max) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double value;
    System.out.print(prompt + " :");
    while (true) {
        value = scan.nextDouble();
        if (value < min || value > max)
            System.out.println("Enter value between " + min + " & " + max);
        else
            break;
    }
    return value;
}
```

}